# How can I speed up Python's 'unittest' on multicore machines?

Tags: python, multithreading, unit-testing, performance, multicore

I'm using the Python *[unittest](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unittest.html)* in order to test some other external application, but it takes too much time to run the tests one by one.

How can I speed up this process by using the power of multicore CPUs? Can I tweak *unittest* to execute tests in parallel? How?

This question is not about the Python [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock) limitation, because in fact it is not the Python code that takes time, but the external application that I execute, currently via `os.system()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your tests are not too involved, you may be able to run them using [py.test](http://pytest.org/) which has [support for distributed testing](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-xdist). If you are not running on Windows, then [nose](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/multiprocess.html) might also work for you.

Comment: py.test looks very well, I will try to see how can I generate the tests dynamically.

Comment: for some reason py.test doesn't want to run my test well, take a look at http://bitbucket.org/hpk42/py-trunk/issue/76/distributed-test-do-not-work-with-pytest_generate_tests

Comment: issue reported by "Sorin Sbarnea" was solved few months later.

Answer (score 4):

The [testtools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/testtools) package is an extension of unittest which supports running tests concurrently. It can be used with your old test classes that inherit `unittest.TestCase`.

For example:

```
import unittest
import testtools

class MyTester(unittest.TestCase):
    # Tests...

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(MyTester)
concurrent_suite = testtools.ConcurrentStreamTestSuite(lambda: ((case, None) for case in suite))
concurrent_suite.run(testtools.StreamResult())
```

Comment: Just tested this with python 2.7 and there was no change, my unit-tests still run in serially.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can run each test on a different process using the `multiprocessing` library. This implies that each unit test (or group of unit tests) should be independent and doesn't need to share the state.
It will open other processes, and will make use of other cores.

Check specifically the 'Using a pool of workers' on this page ( http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers)

**EDIT:** This module is included since version 2.6

Answer (score -1):

As the [vinay-sajip answer suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074074/how-can-i-speed-up-pythons-unittest-on-muticore-machines/2074123#2074123), a few non-core Python packages, like `py.test` and `nose`, provided parallel execution of unit tests via the `multiprocessing` library right out of the box.

However, one thing to consider is that if you are testing a web application with a database backend and majority of your test cases are relying on connecting to the same test database, then your unit test execution speed is bottlenecked on the DB not I/O per se. And using `multiprocess` won't speed it up.

Given that each unit test case requires an independent setup of the database schema + data, you cannot scale out the execution speed only on CPU, but restricted with a single test database connection to a single test database server (otherwise the state of the data may interfere with other other while parallel executing each test case so on and so forth).