# Can Python's unittest test in parallel, like nose can?

Tags: python, unit-testing

Python's NOSE testing framework has the concept of [running multiple tests in parallel](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/multiprocess.html).

The purpose of this is not to test concurrency in the code, but to make tests for code that has "no side-effects, no ordering issues, and no external dependencies" run faster. The performance gain comes from concurrent I/O waits when they are accessing different devices, better use of multi CPUs/cores, and by running time.sleep() statements in parallel.

I believe the same thing could be done with Python's unittest testing framework, by having a plugin Test Runner.

Has anyone had any experience with such a beast, and can they make any recommendations?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074074/how-to-speedup-python-unittest-on-muticore-machines

Comment: You should mock your sleeps, so you don't have to wait from them in your tests.

Comment: @Ytsen: Yes, it is often useful, but that 'should' hides a large number of assumptions about the nature of the testing. The sleeps are often appropriate.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Python unittest's builtin testrunner does not run tests in parallel.  It probably wouldn't be too hard write one that did.  I've written my own just to reformat the output and time each test.  That took maybe 1/2 a day.  I think you can swap out the TestSuite class that is used with a derived one that uses multiprocess without much trouble.

Comment: I accepted this answer, because the implication is that there is no off-the-shelf one available now.

Comment: @Oddthinking did you ever do this?

Comment: @wkschwartz: Not this way. I had a play with some multi-process test-running code completely independent of the unittest framework. It required examination of each test-case to confirm it was completely independent of any other test - a lot of tests had unpredicted interactions.

Answer (score 23):

The [testtools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/testtools) package is an extension of unittest which supports running tests concurrently. It can be used with your old test classes that inherit `unittest.TestCase`.

For example:

```
import unittest
import testtools

class MyTester(unittest.TestCase):
    # Tests...

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(MyTester)
concurrent_suite = testtools.ConcurrentStreamTestSuite(lambda: ((case, None) for case in suite))
concurrent_suite.run(testtools.StreamResult())
```

Comment: Just tested this today and my tests still run in sequence :-(

Comment: When I tried to run this, the system hanged due to out of memory

Answer (score 8):

Please use [pytest-xdist](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-xdist), if you want parallel run.

> The pytest-xdist plugin extends py.test with some unique test execution modes:
>
> - test run parallelization: if you have multiple CPUs or hosts you can use those for a combined test run. This allows to speed up development or to use special resources of remote machines.
>
> [...]

More info: [Rohan Dunham's blog](https://qxf2.com/blog/xdist-run-tests-parallel-pytest/)

Comment: If you also want to generate junitxml report, then this is your only choice

Answer (score 7):

If you only need Python3 suport, consider using my [fastunit](https://github.com/ityoung/python3-fastunit).

I just change few code of unittest, making test case run as coroutines.

It really saved my time.

I just finished it last week, and may not testing enough, if any error happens, please let me know, so that I can make it better, thanks!

Comment: thanks for help me correct my expression :D, I just change the code to `async/await` style, so now it **only support python 3.5+**, still hope everyone can use it to increase efficiency.

Comment: Running your tests asynchronously does not run them in parallel and as such, it should not improve the execution time of your tests. If it does, however, then you should really consider mocking some of your asynchronous code.

Answer (score 7):

Another option that might be easier, if you don't have that many test cases and they are not dependent, is to kick off each test case manually in a separate process.

For instance, open up a couple tmux sessions and then kick off a test case in each session using something like:

```
python -m unittest -v MyTestModule.MyTestClass.test_n
```

Answer (score 5):

You can override the `unittest.TestSuite` and implement some concurrency paradigm. Then, you use your customized `TestSuite` class just like normal `unittest`. In the following example, I implement my customized `TestSuite` class using `async`:

```
import unittest
import asyncio

class CustomTestSuite(unittest.TestSuite):
    def run(self, result, debug=False):
        """
        We override the 'run' routine to support the execution of unittest in parallel
        :param result:
        :param debug:
        :return:
        """
        topLevel = False
        if getattr(result, '_testRunEntered', False) is False:
            result._testRunEntered = topLevel = True
        asyncMethod = []
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        for index, test in enumerate(self):
            asyncMethod.append(self.startRunCase(index, test, result))
        if asyncMethod:
            loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(asyncMethod))
        loop.close()
        if topLevel:
            self._tearDownPreviousClass(None, result)
            self._handleModuleTearDown(result)
            result._testRunEntered = False
        return result

    async def startRunCase(self, index, test, result):
        def _isnotsuite(test):
            "A crude way to tell apart testcases and suites with duck-typing"
            try:
                iter(test)
            except TypeError:
                return True
            return False

        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        if result.shouldStop:
            return False

        if _isnotsuite(test):
            self._tearDownPreviousClass(test, result)
            self._handleModuleFixture(test, result)
            self._handleClassSetUp(test, result)
            result._previousTestClass = test.__class__

            if (getattr(test.__class__, '_classSetupFailed', False) or
                    getattr(result, '_moduleSetUpFailed', False)):
                return True

        await loop.run_in_executor(None, test, result)

        if self._cleanup:
            self._removeTestAtIndex(index)

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')


    def test_isupper(self):
        self.assertTrue('FOO'.isupper())
        self.assertFalse('Foo'.isupper())


    def test_split(self):
        s = 'hello world'
        self.assertEqual(s.split(), ['hello', 'world'])
        # check that s.split fails when the separator is not a string
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            s.split(2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = CustomTestSuite()
    suite.addTest(TestStringMethods('test_upper'))
    suite.addTest(TestStringMethods('test_isupper'))
    suite.addTest(TestStringMethods('test_split'))
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

In the `main`, I just construct my customized `TestSuite` class `CustomTestSuite`, add all the test cases, and finally run it.

Answer (score 2):

## If this is what you did initially

```
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
runner.run(suite)
```

## -----------------------------------------

## replace it with

```
from concurrencytest import ConcurrentTestSuite, fork_for_tests

concurrent_suite = ConcurrentTestSuite(suite, fork_for_tests(4))
runner.run(concurrent_suite)
```

Comment: Where did this module come from? Is it this one: https://github.com/cgoldberg/concurrencytest ?

Comment: Good! I've used it recently and it works really well for me.