# Unittest in parallel

Tags: python, unit-testing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can Python's unittest test in parallel, like nose can?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710142/can-pythons-unittest-test-in-parallel-like-nose-can)

I have tests that are used with unittest and they are run 1 by 1. I would like to run them in parallel because I have a lot of wait so it would go much faster.
Is it possible ? I can't find a solution on the internet eventhough many ppl are talking about it.

Comment: Indeed I have seen this post but I was wondering if there was a better solution today. If not, I will go for it, but I don't like the idea of several implementation for this unittest feature.

Comment: This is not a forum.  Asking duplicate questions should be avoided, and this one is an exact duplicate.  If the existing answer does not help you, chances are that asking it again won't help you either.

Answer (score 2):

You could alternatively parallelize via the shell, no? I just tried this command

```
find -type f -name "_test_*.py" | sed 's/^\.\///; s/\.py$//; s/\//./g;' | xargs -t -P 10 -n 2 python -m unittest
```

The `find` outputs a list of test files, so adapt the filename pattern to your naming convention. The `sed` transforms the found paths to valid module names. The `xargs` starts, in this example, up to 10 processes each running 2 test modules.

I'm not sure yet how to make sense of the output ...

Comment: There's also [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/s/parallel/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use nosetests (easy_install nose) to discover and run pyunit tests. Nose has an options to run them in parallel.

Comment: And those options would be? You should give as full an answer as possible. Tell us what the option is.