# Cause a test to use the multiprocessing capabilities of my server

Tags: python, unit-testing, gevent

I have a Python server application that can prefork gevent Streamserver into multiple processes to exploit multiple CPU cores.

The common gevent server test-case works. However, I don't know how to launch tests that I know will definitely **exercise the multiprocessing capabilities of my server**. Note here that I'm not asking how to run tests in parallel but how to have a test that will cause my server to use its multiprocessing capabilities *while the test is running* and have a way to tell that these capabilities are used.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are looking for a way to exercise the multiprocessing capabilities of your server. If this is the case, then you should emphasize this in your question because the one answer you got right now does not address this. Or if it is *not* the case, then your question definitely needs clarification.

Comment: Yes, I need to test the multiprocessing capabilities of my server app.

Comment: @Louis Can you help me with clarification? English is not my mother tongue.

Comment: I've edited your post.

Answer (score 1):

The [testtools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/testtools) package is an extension of unittest which supports running tests concurrently. It can be used with your old test classes that inherit `unittest.TestCase`.

For example:

```
import unittest
import testtools

class MyTester(unittest.TestCase):
    # Tests...

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(MyTester)
concurrent_suite = testtools.ConcurrentStreamTestSuite(lambda: ((case, None) for case in suite))
concurrent_suite.run(testtools.StreamResult())
```

This answer is not my work, it is from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17059844/3767980