# How to add a custom test runner to a Jetbrains IDE

Tags: python, unit-testing, intellij-idea, pycharm

Pycharm (and the rest of the Jetbrains IDEs) comes with the ability to choose [different testing frameworks](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/choosing-your-testing-framework.html) for running unit tests within itself.
I would like to create a [custom test runner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51430159) which will be capable of running tests in parallel, to speed things up when running independent tests.

- How would I go about integrating this into Pycharm, to add it as an additional test runner?
- Would I have to write a bunch of wrappers for one of the existing test runners like `unittest`?

Comment: PyCharm test runner protocol is described here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/~link/PyCharm+test+runners+protocol

Comment: @PavelKarateev The website is not publicly accessible now :(

Comment: @GeorgeSovetov Reuploaded https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/PyCharm+test+runners+protocol

Comment: Hi Pavel, the reupload is also not working. Can you send an updated link?