# A simple, working example for testtools ConcurrentStreamTestSuite

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I'm looking for a simple example demonstrating how to use [testtool's](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/testtools) concurrent tests.  I've found one example, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074074/how-to-speedup-python-unittest-on-muticore-machines):

```
import unittest
import testtools

class MyTester(unittest.TestCase):
    # Tests...

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(MyTester)
concurrent_suite = testtools.ConcurrentStreamTestSuite(lambda: ((case, None) for case in suite))
concurrent_suite.run(testtools.StreamResult())
```

However, it suffers from a rather large problem.  It doesn't tell you if your tests passed or failed.  Not only is the StreamResult object temporary, StreamResult's methods don't do anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According ot the [`StreamResult` documentation](https://github.com/testing-cabal/testtools/blob/master/doc/for-framework-folk.rst#streamresult), the `status` method is called to handle event, and default implementation does nothing.

To make it print something you need to inherit it to do what you want. For example, to print what's going on:

```
import unittest
import testtools

class MyTester(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        self.assertEqual(1+2, 2)
    def test_foo2(self):
        self.assertEqual(1+2, 3)

class TracingStreamResult(testtools.StreamResult):
    def status(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('{0[test_id]}: {0[test_status]}'.format(kwargs))

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(MyTester)
concurrent_suite = testtools.ConcurrentStreamTestSuite(lambda: ((case, None) for case in suite))
result = TracingStreamResult()
result.startTestRun()
concurrent_suite.run(result)
result.stopTestRun()
```

But, there are already multiple classes that inherit the `StreamResult`. So you maybe not needed to define your own version. See [Extensions to TestResult](http://testtools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/for-framework-folk.html#extensions-to-testresult).

Comment: This helps. do you know of an implementation that prints the errors and the status in the end? instead of me writing one myself?

Comment: @Dejell, Sorry, but I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [concurrencytest](https://github.com/cgoldberg/concurrencytest) library which already implemented testtools classes

Comment: That's great and am using it sucessfully in psutil but it does not support Windows. Both testtools and subunit looks great in terms of code quality and doc, but it's incredible they don't provide a sample on how to use the APIs in order to write a simple parallel test runner.