# How to run unittest in parallel?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have been looking for a bit and I can not find a way to run unittest's in parallel is there a library that gives you the same output but runs the tests in parallel?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to speedup python unittest on muticore machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074074/how-to-speedup-python-unittest-on-muticore-machines)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Python's unittest test in parallel, like nose can?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710142/can-pythons-unittest-test-in-parallel-like-nose-can)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pytest` testing framework has a plugin called `pytest-xdist` that runs tests in parallel.

Note that:

> `pytest` supports running Python `unittest`-based tests out of the box.